# how to center grid using 960 grid system

Tags: html, css, centering, 960.gs

I'm trying to center the grid_5 into the container_12 but without any success. Do you have any idea how to center grid_5. I'm using the grid system 960

```
<article class="container_12">
        <section id="signupform" class="grid_5">
            <form action="">
                <div>
                    <label>Username*</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" autofocus>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Password*</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password">
                </div>
                <div
                    <label>Conferma Password*</label>
                    <input type="password" name="confirm_password">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>E-mail*</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email">
                </div>
            </form>
        </section>
    </article>
```

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle please ?

Comment: Here is it the jsfiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/AYmFL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this css:

`.container_12 .grid_5 {
    width: 380px;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}`

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AYmFL/2/